# Managing database transactions manually in a Spring/Hibernate environment

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring, transactions

We've got a Spring based web application that makes use of Hibernate to load/store its entities to the underlying database.

Since it's a backend application we not only want to allow our UI but also 3rd party tools to manually initiate DB transactions. That's why the callers need to

1. Call a `StartTransaction` method and in return get an ID that they can refer to
2. Do all DB relevant calls (e. g. creating, modifying, deleting) by referring to this ID to make clear which operations belong to the started transaction
3. Call the `CommitTransaction` method to signal to our backend that the transaction can be committed now (or in the negative case `RollbackTransaction` will be called)

So keeping in mind, that all database handling will be done internally by the Java persistence annotations, how can we open the transaction management to our UI that behaves like a 3rd party application that has no direct access to the backend entities but deals with data transfer objects only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this *can* be done but would be a royal pain to implement/verify. You would basically require a transaction manager which is not bounded by "per-thread-transaction" definition but spans across multiple invocations for the same client.

JTA + Stateful session beans might be something you would want to have a look at.

Comment: You are of course welcome. BTW, this community would be interested in the approach you take if you manage to pull this off so would be nice if you could update your original post or comment on this post once you are done with your implementation. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the Spring Reference: [Programmatic transaction management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-programmatic)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build services around your 'back end application' for example a SOAP interface or a REST interface.

With this strategy you can manage your transaction in the backend

Comment: Maybe I didn't clearify my question enough: the keypoint is not which interface to provide but how to have Hibernate offering me a possibility start and end transactions manually. Usually this is all done via annotations and configuration, but our 3rd party tools and the UI do not have access to those annotated entities. Instead they pass DTO (data transfer objects only).